# Animating to the predictedEndTranslation of a DragGesture on a SwiftUI view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to place a view at the predicted location of a `DragGesture`, that's what I do in my `.gestureEnded` closure, wrapping the change in a `withAnimation` block. Yet, when I try it in the live view, the change isn't animated.

Is this a bug of the framework or am I doing something wrong?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var ty: CGFloat = 0

    var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { theGesture in
                self.ty = theGesture.translation.height
                print("Changed")
            }
            .onEnded { theGesture in
                print("Ended")
                withAnimation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 3)) {
                    self.ty = theGesture.predictedEndTranslation.height
                }
            }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(1 ..< 5) { _ in

                Color.red
                    .frame(minHeight: 20, maxHeight: 100)
                    .padding(0)

            }
        }
        .transformEffect(.init(translationX: 0, y: ty))
        .gesture(dragGesture)
    }

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Trevor, your .onChange() already translated your view. Is the onChange() there just for debugging?

Comment: @kontiki Hey! Sorry I did a mistake, I wanted to use theGesture.predictedEndTranslation.height. Updated the question

Comment: No worries, posted an answer.

Comment: By the way, some animations do not work on Xcode's Live Preview. You need to run on a device or the simulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems `translateEffect` cannot be animated. It kind of makes sense, since CGAffineTransform does not conform to `Animatable`, so that might be as intended. Fortunately, you can still use `.offset(x: 0, y: ty)`.

Will that work for you?

***Note that some animations (like this one), do not work in Xcode Live Preview. You need to run it on a device or the simulator.***

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't found `.offset` yet. My issue is that it still doesn't animate even on my device.

Comment: When I saw you said it didn't work in Xcode Live Preview, I didn't thought it applied to on device live preview too...

Comment: So now that I ran it directly on device like a normal app, it works properly! Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You're welcome. I find Live Previews to be too unreliable for the moment. For the time being, I stopped using them, as it saves time to work directly on the simulator. Otherwise I have to keep double checking.

Answer (score 3):

An example implementation of the effect for SwiftUI/iOS 13.4, also fixing the view jumping around when dragged repeatedly.

The trick is to use `@GestureState` to keep track of the gesture in progress and to keep the overall state change separately, applying the changes with the `.offset` modifier:

```swift
struct DragGestureView: View {

    @GestureState var dragOffset = CGSize.zero
    @State var offset: CGFloat = 0

    var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .updating($dragOffset) { value, state, _ in
                state = value.translation
            }
            .onEnded { gesture in
                // keep the offset already moved without animation
                self.offset += gesture.translation.height
                withAnimation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 3)) {
                    self.offset += gesture.predictedEndTranslation.height - gesture.translation.height
                }
            }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(1 ..< 5) { _ in
                Color.red
                    .frame(minHeight: 20, maxHeight: 100)
            }
        }
        .offset(x: 0, y: offset + dragOffset.height)
        .gesture(dragGesture)
    }

}

struct DragGestureView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DragGestureView()
    }
}
```

[Runnable example via Github: SwiftUIPlayground](https://github.com/ralfebert/SwiftUIPlayground/blob/master/SwiftUIPlayground/Views/DragGestureView.swift)